# NSDateFormatter "w"

Tags: objective-c

In my app, I used "w" to format date:

1. With "w", does a new week start on Sundays?
2. The date is local right?

Answer (score 2):

NSDateFormatter will use your location settings (See [NSLocal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).
So If canadian is your local and canadian calendars starts on Saturday this is your week.

Answer (score 2):

For your question about the week element,

The following is from [HERE](http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format), your NSDateFormatter uses the ISO Standard.

> Week date is an alternative date representation used in many
>   commercial and industrial applications. It is: YYYY-Www-D
>
> where YYYY is the Year in the Gregorian calendar, ww is the week of
>   the year between 01 (the first week) and 52 or 53 (the last week), and
>   D is the day in the week between 1 (Monday) and 7 (Sunday).
>
> Example: 2003-W14-2 represents the second day of the fourteenth week
>   of 2003.

This means that for the Gregorian calendar, the weeks start on Mondays.

In additions to PascalTurbo's post, if you need to, you can explicitly set set the timezone for your date formatter like the following example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```